# Is it possible to generate an accurate volume profile in python that will have the same values as TradingView?

Tags: python, trading, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api, indicator

I am working on a python script that would be able to produce Volume Profile (especially VAH/VAL values).

I am using the FTX API to get historical volume data.
https://docs.ftx.com/#get-historical-prices

I am using a 15min timeframe, and I read on the TradingView blog that they are using 1-minute data. https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile/

```
    globalRegister = pd.DataFrame()
    #Scan every 8 hours, 480min, 28,800sec
    for a in range(20):
        if a == 0:
            globalRegister = self.api.get_historical_prices(market=self.marketname, start_time = time.time() - 28800, end_time = time.time(), resolution=timeFrame)
            globalRegister = pd.DataFrame(globalRegister)
            continue
        end_time = time.time() - ((a) * 28800)
        start_time = time.time()- ((a+1) * 28800)
        historical = self.api.get_historical_prices(market=self.marketname, start_time = start_time, end_time = end_time, resolution=timeFrame)
        historical = pd.DataFrame(historical)
        globalRegister = pd.concat([historical, globalRegister], ignore_index= True)
    print(globalRegister)
    return globalRegister
```

Later I am plugging this data into this library.
https://github.com/bfolkens/py-market-profile

And yet the output I get is similar to the one on TradingView but it is not accurate enough, and sometimes my output is not matching at all.

Is it even possible to get the same results as on TradingView?
I am really frustrated, and I would be really grateful for help :)
Chart: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=FTX%3ABTCPERP

Comment: Is it at all possible to calculate this volume profile metrics without digesting tick-level market data? How is it possible having bar data (whether 1-minute or 15-minute bars) to assign their associated volumes to very specific prices. If done by averaging, I would assume that the higher the volatility of the market the less precise the volume profile become in such case. Because the bars will have larger High to Low ranges and the bar volume will have to be attributed to a wider range of prices. Or I miss something, do I?

Comment: Hello, it is assigned to the candle's close price in my script, I even tried to play with it but it still was not accurate. As far as I understand from this post-https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile they are actually not using tick level data. But I am unsure what price they are assigning the volume to. Can you think of some work-around so I could get VAH, VAL from tradingview? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I think that assigning the whole bar volume to the Close price of the bar is fundamentally incorrect (and the larger the timespan of the bar, 15m vs. 1m for instance, the more biased the profile will be). If the futures is traded 24 hours a day, I will have only 96 fifteen-minute volumes. If the futures price step is $0.25 and the daily range is $100, I will need to make a histogram of 96 volumes on the domain of 401 price points. I can only imagine how weird and fragmented that daily volume histogram will be. I wonder why you desire to stick to the way it is done dy tradingview?

Comment: The problem is that we tested all our strategies on Tradingview, and if we were to change the volume profile now we would need to update our strategy. Also, Tradingview has some options that make it less fragmented and more usable. These are the settings we use [link](https://imgur.com/a/YDYITJY). In this case, the number of rows is fixed. Looks like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/jcjCKRX). For our strategy to work I need to get the blue lines in the chart.

Comment: I just ran the script, and for yesterday (8.8) it was correct. We are calculating the Volume Profile for every day (24 hours). VAH VAL were correct, but I need for the script to work 100% of the time. One thing I can think of is manually setting it but that would be tiring. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Understood. I would retest the strategy with purchased tick-level (or at least one-second-bar) data and the volume profile I completely understand how is formed. Just imagine that the tradingview team will decide one day that they need to change the way this profile is calculated - how much exposure to the risk you'll get even not being aware of that.

Comment: I also have one objection to the (perceived) strategy as I see it on your screenshot - imagine that you are in the middle of the sixth hour (let's call the time 5:30) (at the time just before the break up after testing the level at the previous high-volume "level"). You still can't see the largest volume, which will form by 6:45, so it triggers you to short.  Potentially if you tested full-day charts only, the strategy may retrospectively predict turnovers.